# sending email via nodemailer not working

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have a simple piece of code which is not working as expected. I am using nodemailer.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'personal gmail address',
    pass: 'password'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'personal gmail address',
    to: 'personal gmail address',
    subject: 'Hello world!',
    text: 'Plaintext message example.'
};

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
  console.log('Message sent!');
});
```

I am getting the Message Sent in console. But no emails in inbox.

Comment: Check your spam folder

Comment: @admix, nope nothing in spam folder too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For gmail service I use this :

```
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'email',
    pass: 'pass'
  }
}))
```

But you need to allow less secure authentication on your gmail account or emails are not sent. 
I think the steps are :

- Go to : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
- set the Access for less secure apps setting to Enable

Comment: @jaumard...that did not work. i had made the setting change already.

Comment: disable your anti virus and try it. I am able to do it

Answer (score 1):

Found this SO: [self signed certificate in certificate chain error in mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764215/self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-error-in-mail) .
I needed to add this and it worked for me.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
           user: 'myemail@gmail.com', 
           pass: 'password' 
          },
    tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check for the error message.

```
...
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
  if(err)
  {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('Message sent!');
  }
});
```

Because in the sample code you had, even if the nodemailer returns valid error, it will still print **Message Sent**

Some times message can be queued or say any type of error in the mailOptions, the message cant be delivered.